# How to temporarily suppress image insertion when compiling?

Tags: graphics, pdf, compiling, dvi

There are some big images in my document and compiling is taking substantial amount of time.  When compiling a tex file to a dvi (and subsequently ps and pdf), is there any way I can temporarily suppress insertion of eps files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `draft` option of the `graphicx` package. Then you get only an rectangle with the filename in place of your picture.

Comment: Wonderful! Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you very much...